# UIAlertController is not getting dismissed

Tags: xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin iOS app, I have a static helper method that displays an alert dialog. This dialog box needs to automatically go away after a few seconds if the user has still not pressed OK button. Here is the simplified code snippet:

```
 UIAlertController dlg = UIAlertController.Create(title, text,
     UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
 dlg.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null);
 UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.
    PresentViewController(dlg, true, null);
```

Later, when the timer expires:

```
 t.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
     dlg.DismissViewController(true, null);
 };
```

Although, the method `DismissViewController` is indeed getting invoked, the dialog does not disappear from the screen.

I even tried calling `dlg.Dispose()` but this didn't help either.

Can someone please help me understand what is it that I am missing? Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in event **Elapsed** is not on the main Thread .

Invoke it on Main Thread.

```
t.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
{
   InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
       dlg.DismissViewController(true, null);
   });
};
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.